# Is the use of semi-colon correct here?

Tags: semicolons

Consider the following sentence:

> "Walker was not only the trailblazer in the medical field; she was also a visionary who bravely challenged many of the social prejudices of her day. "

My question is that whether it is appropriate to use semi-colons here because the first clause doesn't seem to be an independent one since it doesn't convey a complete idea.

Comment: It should be a colon, not a semi-colon, since it **expands on** the first part of the sentence.

Comment: I agree with Max Williams: for the reason he has given, a colon would suit.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Not in the manner a colon would do.

Comment: @Kris Have some comments been deleted? The thread doesn't make sense. Even allowing for MW's non-corresponding _it_'s. Or are those what you're referring to?

Comment: I think that 'not only' and 'also' allow the use of a comma here. I think that both semi-colon and colon are superfluous.

Comment: I agree that a comma is technically correct. However, I would choose a semicolon myself. I wish I knew or could explain why that is my strong preference

Comment: @NigelJ Maybe in the absence of "but" (in "but also") it needs to be a semicolon?

Answer (score 2):

A comma belongs here. A semi-colon links two independent clauses that are closely related in thought, which is not what you have here.

Your thought that "...because the first clause doesn't seem to be an independent one since it doesn't convey a complete idea" is the exact reason why you need a comma instead of a semi-colon, because it's a dependent clause.

Answer (score 2):

Though the usage [has been criticized,](https://sec.theglobeandmail.com/arts/books-and-media/conjunctions-get-no-respect/article4485729/lib/proxies/) *not only ... [but] also* functions as a coordinating conjunction even without the contrasting *but*, thus not requiring a semicolon to join two independent clauses. Since there appears to be a question whether this is indeed the case, look at the clauses without the conjunction:

> Walker was a trailblazer in the medical field.
>
> She was a visionary who bravely challenged many of the social prejudices of her day.

Both clauses have the structure Subj. + copula + predicate noun — clearly independent clauses.

The lack of the contrasting *but* does, however, suggest a colon might even add more drama to this sentence, as others have suggested. Whichever you decide, a semicolon would be the wrong punctuation here.

Comment: See Marty Jo Thomas.

Comment: What about her? The two clauses are independent. No semicolon, but for the wrong reason.

Comment: No, you need the _but_ in _but also_.

Comment: Oh, how I love precriptivist fervor! I can't remember ever having personally omitted the _but_, but I don't miss it horribly in this particular sentence. We can at least agree and stick in a colon. Then everybody's happy.

Answer (score 0):

[image: here]

I concur with most of the answers here. The reason I doubt (With due respect) is that it is the official answer posted by Khan Academy (partnered with College Board).
I cut the sentence short for the sake of simplicity. Kindly see the full question here and see if this conveys a hint or there's an error on their part.

Comment: 1)There is no possible way under the rules of English grammar that "Walker was not only a trailblazer in the medical field" is a relative clause. 2) A semicolon _never_ sets off a relative clause from an independent one. Ever.

Comment: Now one could argue that since _but_ is a coordinating conjunction when used alone it is an essential part of _not only...but also_, thus its omission would require a semicolon, but here, Khan is misapplying a rule that doesn't exist. Quite an accomplishment!